# Excel Sumif, Sumifs with partial strings in multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So this is the simplified question I broke down from a former question I had here: [Excel help on combination of Index - match and sumifs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583924/excel-help-on-combination-of-index-match-and-sumifs) .

For this one, I have `Table1` (the black-gray one) with two or more columns for adjustments for various order numbers. See this image below:
[image]

What I want to achieve is to have total adjustments for those order numbers that contain the numbers in Total Adjustment column in the blue table, each of which will depend on the cell beside it.

Example: Order number 17051 has two products: 17051A (Apple) and 17051B (Orange).

Now what I want to achieve in cell C10 is the sum of adjustment for both 17051A and 17051B, which will be: Apple Adjustment (5000) + Orange Adjustment (4500) = 9500.

The formula I used below (and in the image) kept giving me error messages, and this happens even before I add the adjustment for Orange.

```
=SUMIF(Text(LEFT(Table1[Order Number],5),"00000"),text(B10,"00000"),Table1[Apple Adjustment])
```

I have spent the whole day looking for a solution for this and didn’t even come close to find any. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your headers always have the text "adjustment" in them, you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT($B$4:$B$7,5)=B10&"")*(RIGHT($C$3:$F$3,10)="adjustment")*$C$4:$F$7)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, Rory! This works awesome for my problem, so thanks a lot again! Now I have to go learn more about the sumproduct syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

In C10 you could add two sumproducts. This assumes that products are always 5 numbers long at the start. If not swop the 5 to use the length of the product reference part you are matching on.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(1*LEFT($B$4:$B$7,5)=$B10),$D$4:$D$7)+SUMPRODUCT(--(1*LEFT($B$4:$B$7,5)=$B10),$F$4:$F$7)
```

Which with table syntax is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(1*LEFT(Table1[Order Number],5)=$B10),Table1[Apple Adjustment])+SUMPRODUCT(--(1*LEFT(Table1[Order Number],5)=$B10),Table1[Orange Adjustment])
```

Using LEN

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(1*LEFT(Table1[Order Number],LEN($B10))=$B10),Table1[Apple Adjustment])+SUMPRODUCT(--(1*LEFT(Table1[Order Number],LEN($B10))=$B10),Table1[Orange Adjustment])
```

I am multiplying by 1 to ensure Left, 5 becomes numeric.

Comment: Hi QHarr! Thanks for answering (again :) )! I tried your code but have some difficulties in applying it to my immediate problem now, so for now I'll go with Rory's answer. But I really appreciate your answering, and I will definitely go back to your solution and study it when I have the time. So in the mean time could you explain why you have three rows of formula here, or do you mean to combine them three in C10? Thanks very much!

Comment: It is just the last one you need. The other two are different versions of the same thing. The last one is the most versatile. The last one caters for the number part being different lengths.